# Using Linq Select to create a new inherited object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, inheritance

I have 2 classes, `User` and `ExtendedUser`. `ExtendedUser` inherits from `User` and just adds 2 `int` fields - Nothing fancy.

I have a list of `User` objects - `List<User>` and would like to go over the list and create a list of `ExtendedUser` objects, where I'd like to just fill fill the missing `int` fields.

I thought about using the `Select` method of Linq to create the new objects, but it won't copy the `User` to `ExtendedUser` - so I'll need to recreate those objects, which doesn't make sense for me.

EDIT:

`User` is an Entity, where as `ExtendedUser` is a custom class inheriting from that entity (but not an entity by itself).

It seems the easiest solution here would be composition, though conceptually - inheritance would have worked better.

Any smart solutions here? :)

Thanks!

Comment: The issue is that User object is created by Entity Framework, which also includes a lot of functionality for this object - So I can't easily copy it.

Comment: How about `ExtendedUser`? Is it created by `EntityFramework` too?

Comment: When ExtendedUser is an entity (as it should be) this is trivial with `OfType<>`. When you don't want it in the Db, consider composition instead of inheritance. But do provide the extra information.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - ExtendedUser is NOT an entity, just a custom class. I did go with composition for now as I can't find a straight forward enough solution otherwise.

Comment: Yes inheritance between an entity and a non-entity is pretty strange concept, not easy to deal with. So backtrack how you got to that solution and ask if you really need it. Adding 2 dummy fields (and maybe a discriminator) to the entity might be an alternative.

Comment: And do edit the question with this info. Comments don't count here.

Comment: Easy solution is to simply add your two properties into `User`. Decorate them with `[NotMapped]`. Then use `ObjectMaterialized` event and in it initalize those two properties.Indeed `ExtendedUser` is no longer needed.

Comment: Yes, `[Notmapped]` might provide sort of an answer but should there really be 2 types to start with? Iow, does your app also use User objects that are not ExtendedUser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ... of Linq to create the new objects, but it won't copy the User to ExtendedUser - so I'll need to recreate those objects, which doesn't make sense for me.

This is not a shortcoming of Linq.

It is a general principal in strongly typed OOP that you cannot simply convert base class objects to derived objects. Such a conversion always involves copying the members and that raises the issue of identity (which clone is the real one?).

In other words, when an object is supposed to be of class B it should never have started life as type A, even if B derives from A. So do revisit your design and overall solution.

When you still think you need this, then what you have is a situation like converting entities to DTOs and vice versa. And you can use the usual tools like AutoMapper.

Comment: This actually makes sense :) So composition it is!